How to manage application.properties in Github CI/CD
I have a Spring API, and I am setting up my CI/CD pipeline to run tests after each push to the master branch.
I have an application-test.properties file that I use for my tests, but I avoid pushing this file to my repository because it contains sensitive information. To manage this, I’ve created secrets in my repository settings to store this data.
I understand that I can map these secrets to my application.properties file using the following syntax:
env: 
SPRING_DATA_MONGODB_URI: ${{ secrets.MONGODB_URI }}

However, since I don’t push my application.properties files to the repository, I cannot use this approach.
My question is: Is it considered good practice to include application.properties files in a repository? If so, how can I manage the situation where local development lacks data due to the use of ${{ secrets.xxx }}?
I can't find a clear answer to this question about best practice.

Usually the file application.properties is versioned at the repository level; it is the files e.g. application-test.properties that are not versioned so that each developer can have their different values locally

Okay I get it. So I can version my application.properties without exposing my sensitive data and locally using application-local.properties for example?

Exaclty; for example if your developers have a local instance of a DB to use when they run the app locally, each one of them will have his own (potentially different) connection string in clear text inside application-test.properties

Okay I understand better now. Thank you very much for your help!

to achieve that, you can try to change your application-test.properties to a dynamic configuration, for example:
myapp.database.username=${DATABASE_USERNAME}
myapp.database.password=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}

and then you have to register the value as env variables to your workflows file,  for example:
name: CI Workflow

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      DATABASE_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.DATABASE_USERNAME }}
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DATABASE_PASSWORD }}
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
....

and don't forget to add your secrets variable on your github repository.
for local situation, you can register your env variables on Run/Debug Configurations if you use intellij idea, for example:


Github provides the ability to store sensitive information you want to hide in repository -> settings -> secrets and variables -> actions.

You can enter the value here along with the name you want and use it in CI/CD as follows:
 - name: Login to DockerHub
        uses: docker/login-action@v1 
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD }}

Or add your file to the server local path in advance, ex) usr/home/bin/app.env
There are also ways to use it.

Okay I get it! So then I can still deploy my application.properties using the environment variable from Github CICD/ right?

Sure, It may vary depending on the deployment environment, but you can use it this way. https://github.com/start-for-legend/chr/blob/develop/.github/workflows/cd.yml
